# XPJS (Javascript XPCOM) Documentation?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, xpcom, gecko, idl

Anyone know where is some usable XPJS, or XPCOM in JS, documentation for recent versions of Firefox/Gecko? And sample code/ tutorials would be great too.

I need to write my own Component, but without .IDL (no C++ compiled interface), so I could access it via

```
Components.classes['@com.mareksebera/compname;1']
                                .getService().wrappedJSObject;
```

or this way is not supported anymore? I can't use

```
Components.classes['@com.mareksebera/compname;1']  
                                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsICompName);
```

Because of missing compiled interface `nsICompName`

And yes, I know that `NSGetModule` is deprecated, and I use `NSGetFactory` and `XPCOMUtils.jsm`

I know these, but those are not usable with up to date browsers versions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Custom_Firefox_Extensions_with_the_Mozilla_Build_System
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XPCOM_in_JavaScript_without_leaking
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_build_an_xpcom_component_in_javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third link you mentioned is pretty good.  Another way to get examples though is to actually [download the Mozilla source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial) and look in the /tests subdirectories.  There are some examples there of javascript created XPCOM objects.

One example that comes to mind can be found at:

> `<mozilla-central>\content\xtf\test\unit`

But there are a ton of examples throughout the codebase.

If you prefer you can also [browse the code online via mxr](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/).